# Автозагрузка классов в PHP

Tags: php, ооп, autoload

Есть переменная:

```
private $_classes = [
    'Component' => '/base/Component.php',
    'Controller' => '/kernel/Controller.php',
    'DataBase' => '/kernel/DataBase.php',
];
```

И есть функция, которая подключает все эти файлы и создаёт по экземпляру объекта для каждого файла:

```
public function autoload() {
    foreach ($this->_classes as $key => $value) {
        $path = base_url . $value;
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            require_once $path;

            return new $key;
        }
    }
}
```

Однако почему-то выполняется этот код только один раз и всё. Если убрать

```
return new $key
```

То всё нормально, все 3 класса инклудятся.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: потому что выполнение метода заканчивается на return во время первой итерации

Answer (score 1):

PHP не знаю, но походу выполняется условие `file_exists($path)` на первой итерации и происходит выход из функции в конструкции `if` на строке

```
return new $key;
```